# QGIS 3 running slowly

Tags: qgis-3, performance, windows-10, context-menu

I've been using QGIS 2.14 pretty successfully for about two years. I do also have Arc but tend to use Q more primarily because it *did* run considerably faster. I then installed QGIS  3 as I noticed it had some really useful functions such as the 'multi edit tool' for the attribute table. However the difference in speed between the two versions is drastic, particularly when working with 'layer properties' or the print composer. More often than not when I open the properties menu my computer freezes and I can go and make a coffee before it's even opened and that's before I've tried to make any changes. Even moving the cursor around at that stage can lead to a 'not responding message'.

As I've not seen any other comments to this effect I can only assume I'm missing something. Perhaps a setting or something. As far as I'm aware I'm not using the program any differently than I was the previous version, but it's currently making a program that transformed the way I work into something that is almost unusable.

Comment: Which QGIS 3 version are you using? I think the latest as of this comment is 3.8.1.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: Performance questions require details on the system being used (CPU, RAM, OS, type of disk (HDD/SSD), and disk seek time (if not SSD)), the actual tasks (including data format and data location), and the time it takes to perform each task, in seconds.

Comment: Sorry I've tried to add some more context:

Qversion is 3.8.1
Windows 10
i5-5300U - CPU @ 2.3GHz
8GB RAM
OS 10586.1540

Going through a network drive but this wasn't an issue previously. I can't directly access the local drive but the machine that Q is installed on is an hp-elitebook-840 if that helps?

Comment: Main issue is when editing properties of a .shp layer the menu can take upwards of 180 seconds just to open and my computer is frozen while it's doing it and it's similar for print composer. It doesn't seem to matter the size of the layer (could have 6000 attributes could have 10). Opening attribute table is has a similar effect but we're only talking 10 seconds or so. Simple algorithms like clipping and selecting by location seem to be unaffected if not slightly quicker. Thanks again. T

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. Using a network drive assures the worst possible GIS performance.  Network driver latency could easily explain your performance issue.

Comment: Just to follow up. Thank you all for the help. I've now been given direct access to the local drive which has resolved the performance issue. Still strange as it wasn't an issue with previous versions so perhaps something to be aware of?